# Confluence Prototype REST API - create a page?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Is it even possible to create a page using the Prototype REST API?

I know how to do this using the REST API (available with Confluence 5.5 and up), but I'm not sure how to do this on older versions.
For new api, I do it like that: `{url}/rest/api/content` and provide parameters like *type*, *space*, *title* and *ancestors*. 
For the Prototype API I've tried to do:
`{url}/rest/prototype/latest/content.json` and provide the same parameters, but I get **"Request failed: method not allowed (405)"** in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the prototype REST API is read-only.

Comment: You might want to mark your answer as THE answer ;)